# How to call C++ constructor from Visual Basic

Tags: c++, vba, dll, com

I'm having trouble calling a C++ constructor in my Visual Basic code. The DLL has been imported correctly but this line in particular is giving me trouble:

```vb
Dim myobj As New MyObject("param1", "param2", "param3")
```

And the corresponding C++ constructor:

```
MyObject::MyObject(System::String ^ p1, System::String ^ p2, System::String ^ p3)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error or result are you seeing?

Comment: "Compile error: Syntax error"

Comment: VBA doesn't support constructors with arguments.

Comment: COM does not support constructors with arguments.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how I create this object?

Comment: VB only supports VB classes and COM objects.  You will have to re-write the DLL into a full blown COM object (or write a separate COM wrapper DLL that accesses the original DLL internally).  COM objects don't allow constructor arguments, so it will have to expose a public method that you can call after the object has been created to pass your values to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. It's simply not supported this way.

The easiest way of doing it is to just convert the constructor into a function (eg `Initialize()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't - the class will be instantiated with a default constructor. If you need parameterized construction you have two options - either add an "initialize" parameterized method to the class or add a factory class with an "instantiate the first class with this parameters" method.

Answer (score 0):

Use abstract interfaces and make factory to generate objects. Also it will keep the abstraction between your code and dll. Read this article
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/howto_export_cpp_classes.aspx